# "The property weight is not recognised by Google for an object of type Offer"

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I have several [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer) items on my page and each of them contains an [`IndivudualProduct`](https://schema.org/IndividualProduct). Inside each `IndivudualProduct` item there is a [`weight`](https://schema.org/weight) property. And it's where I get the following problem:

> The property `weight` is not recognised by Google for an object of type `Offer`

How can I fix this problem?

If I understand correctly, `weight` is a property of `IndividualProduct` inherited by `Product` and `IndividualProduct` must be a property of `Offer`. And I can't have `weight` inside the `Offer`. It seems to be a real vicious circle for me.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a minimal example of the markup that gives this error. You have to format is as code (button in the toolbar, or press Ctrl+k).

Comment: It sounds like you've not nested things properly. We need an example.